# Recorded video using android doesn't play on Blobstore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, video-streaming, blobstore, video-recording

I wrote the code to record a video on android, I upload it to the Blobstore, but no luck in getting it play either from the player on googleappengine or stream it on a web application however, I can read the video when I download it. Any idea ?? I thought of the encodings I am using or the video format(.mp4) or even more, the way i send the bytes to the blobstore. thank you.

here is the recording code:

```
     mCamera = Camera.open();        
     path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();

     Date date=new Date();
     filename="/rec"+date.toString().replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")+".mp4";

     //create empty file it must use
     File file=new File(path,filename);
    mrec = new MediaRecorder(); 
    mCamera.lock();
    mCamera.unlock();
    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);    
    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);     
    mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mrec.setVideoFrameRate(20);
    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    mrec.setOutputFile(path+filename);
    mrec.prepare();
    mrec.start();
```

and here is the uploading code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

//HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
File file = new File("/sdcard/"+videoName);

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "video/mp4");
mpEntity.addPart("videoFile", cbFile);

httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

the "url" parameter is the generated url from the blobstore in order to upload the media file, i guess blobstore users are familiar with it.

Comment: done, I edited the post with the code i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `OutputFormat.MPEG_4`, `VideoEncoder.H264` and `AudioEncoder.AAC`.

Comment: I have tried the modifications you suggested but it seems that now the Blobstore player displays the length of the video, but still no streaming at all. I am really in need for a solution for this. and it seems that there is nothing wrong with the code !